# storing the data of selectonemenu in a list

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

i have an erreur message when i execute this xhtml page , i think that i have a
probleme in my selectonemenu when storing the data in a list with the argument j-1,i-1
this the error message (Grave: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "get")

```
<p:panelGrid  columns="#{horaireBean.listCalendrier.size()+1}"
styleClass="horaire1"  >

<p:outputLabel >
<center>
<h4>Catégorie/Calendrier</h4>
</center>
</p:outputLabel>

<c:forEach var="cal" begin="1"
end="#{horaireBean.listCalendrier.size()}">

<p:outputLabel 
value="#{horaireBean.listCalendrier.get(cal-1).designation}" />

</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="j" begin="1"
end="#{horaireBean.listCategorie.size()}">
<p:outputLabel
value="#{horaireBean.listCategorie.get(j-1).desigCat}" />
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1"
end="#{horaireBean.listCalendrier.size()}">


<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{horaireBean.listehoraire.get(j-1).get(i-1)}"    
styleClass="horaire2" converter="sequenceConverter" >
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{horaireBean.listehoraire.get(j-1).get(i-1).desigSeq}"/>
<f:selectItems value="#{sequencebean.listeSequence}" var="seq" itemLabel="#      
{seq.desigSeq}" itemValue="#{seq}"  />
<p:ajax  event="change"  process="@this"   update=":formheader:enregistrer   
:formheader:annuler"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>


</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: the listhoraire is :  private ArrayList<ArrayList<Sequence>> listehoraire;

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets `[]` instead of curved brackets `()`.

Something like 
`horaireBean.listehoraire.[j-1].[i-1].desigSeq` 
instead of 
`horaireBean.listehoraire.get(j-1).get(i-1).desigSeq`

**Edit :**

What about  `horaireBean.listehoraire.[#{j-1}].[#{i-1}].desigSeq`?

Or

```
<c:set var="myVariable" value="#{j-1}" />
<c:set var="myVariable2" value="#{i-1}" />
```

`horaireBean.listehoraire.[#{myVariable}].[#{myVariable2}].desigSeq`

Comment: i try it but i have an error on syntax ,in horaireBean.listehoraire.[j-1].[i-1]

Comment: Use `c:var` to do j-1 and store the value, then use that var/value inside [] as the index value.